# Is 'For, surely', correct?

Tags: grammar

Proof reading an essay of mine, and have come across a sentence that, now I read it, doesn't seem to sound right to me, yet my friend disagrees and thinks it is correct.

*'For surely, it must be...'*

Is *'For, surely'* incorrect in itself, and should just simply be *'Surely,'* or is it the grammar that I have completely wrong?

Comment: 'For' in this usage is a sentence connector; we can't comment on acceptability until we have the preceding sentence/s.

Comment: Consider that "surely" can be considered something of an interjection and can be elided to analyze the sentence structure -- "For it must be...".  "For can be a stand-in for "thus" or "therefore".

Comment: 'For surely' is an OK sequence of words that should be followed appropriately, but it is not a constituent that stands by itself like 'for sure'. Maybe remove the comma or add one before to get the idea of what the pieces really are.

Comment: Kinda hard to tell since you haven't given the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"For" can be used as a stand in for "because", for example that fairy's words in Sleeping Beauty (I forgot which Disney princess movie, there are 7 of them and counting): "Have no fear, for I am here"

Now, if you replace "for" with "because" it becomes "because surely", which is not wrong. "Surely" is used to emphasize that you think something is what you think it is and it's so obvious it's like common sense, but there's that little inkling doubt that you don't use the general truth model (which is just stating something) and want confirmation